# Dynamically create jQuery Mobile page via JavaScript after clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, jquery-mobile

My jQuery Mobile app consists of a single `index.html` page and contains only one page with a link on startup:

```
<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="content">
    <a id="startPageLink" href="startPage">start</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

When the user clicks on the start link, I want to load the content for the `startPage` from my JSON api asynchronously. On the callback I would like to create all the required DOM elements for `startPage` via JavaScript and add the content to it. I have created a `createStartPage(data)` method for this.

What is the right way to implement such dynamically created pages, so that opening `index.html#startPage` also works? I think there should be a way to hook into `$.mobile.changePage()` to include custom loading/page-creation code, but I did not find anything. Or is there a better solution for this problem?

Comment: The latest version of jQuery Mobile (May 27th) contains changes to how `$.mobile.changePage()` works, which might be useful: http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/05/27/jquery-mobile-team-update-week-of-may-23/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I had some time to mess around with this and I've found a solution that works (tested).

SOME NOTES:

1. the javascript encapsulated in $(document).ready(); is for dynamically creating a page if the user navigates to your index.html file with a hash mark already appended (i.e. index.html#some_hash_mark).
2. The function, create_page(page_id) is for creating a page from a link (or programatically if you like).
3. Note that the jquery core script and the jquery mobile css are loaded before the $(document).ready() statement but that the jquery mobile script is loaded after.
4. See that the body tag has been given an id that is refrenced when appending pages to it.

**Document Sample**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    //check if hash exists and that it is not for the home screen
    if (window.location.hash != '' && window.location.hash != '#page_0') {

        //set whatever content you want to put into the new page
        var content_string = 'Some ' + window.location.hash + ' text...<br><br><a href="#page_0">go to home screen</a>';

        //append the new page onto the end of the body
        $('#page_body').append('<div data-role="page" id="' + window.location.hash.replace('#','') + '"><div data-role="content">' + content_string + '</div></div>');

        //add a link on the home screen to navaigate to the new page (just so nav isn't broken if user goes from new page to home screen)
        $('#page_0 div[data-role="content"]').append('<br><br><a href="#' + window.location.hash.replace('#','') + '">go to ' + window.location.hash.replace('#','') + ' page</a>');
    }
});
function create_page(page_id) {

    //set whatever content you want to put into the new page
    var string = 'FOO BAR page...<br><br><a href="#page_0">return to home screen</a>';

    //append the new page onto the end of the body
    $('#page_body').append('<div data-role="page" id="' + page_id + '"><div data-role="content">' + string + '</div></div>');

    //initialize the new page 
    $.mobile.initializePage();

    //navigate to the new page
    $.mobile.changePage("#" + page_id, "pop", false, true);

    //add a link on the home screen to navaigate to the new page (just so nav isn't broken if user goes from new page to home screen)
    $('#page_0 div[data-role="content"]').append('<br><br><a href="#' + page_id + '">go to ' + page_id + ' page</a>');

    //refresh the home screen so new link is given proper css
    $('#page_0 div[data-role="content"]').page();
}
</script>
<title>Fixed Headers Example</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body id="page_body">
<div data-role="page" id="page_0">
<div data-role="content">Some #page_0 text...<br><br><a href="javascript: create_page('foo_bar_page');">create new page</a></div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This solves the problem how to start with a specific, dynamic page. Thank you. But how to create additional pages on demand (after clicking a <li><a>)?.

Comment: create_page(page_id)... its a function for creating a page from a link. It creates the page, initializes it, then forwards the user to the new page. The specific function I wrote above also creates a link on the homepage so if the user back-tracks to the homepage they can again go forward to the newly created page. This was documented under NOTE #2. `<li><a href="javascript:create_page('page_id_here');">link text</a></li>`

Answer (score 5):

To me Jasper solution doesn't work but i've found [this solution](https://gist.github.com/1037934) that look cleaner and work fine

Comment: This is a _much_ better solution.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my method for dynamically adding content to my Jquery Mobile websites:

1. First I create a "wrapper" data-role=page div like so:

   ```
   <div data-role="page" id="my_page_id">
   <div data-role="content">
       <script>
       $('#my_page_id').live('pageshow', function() {
           my_data_loading_function('my_page_id');
       });
       </script>
   <div id="my_page_id-content"></div>
   </div><!--/content-->
   </div><!--/page-->
   ```
2. Next I load data from an external source into a div tag located in my "wrapper" page:

   ```
   function my_data_loading_function(page) {
       if ($('#' + page + '-content').is(':empty')) {
           $.mobile.pageLoading();
           $('#' + page + '-content').load("my_external_script.php", function() {
               $.mobile.pageLoading(true);
               $('#' + page + '-content ul').listview();
               $('#' + page + '-content ul').page();
           });
       }
   }
   ```

Some Notes:

- $.mobile.pageLoading(); and $.mobile.pageLoading(true); show and hide (respectively) the Jquery Mobile loading spinner.
- if ($('#' + page + '-content').is(':empty')) { allows the user to navaigate away from the dynamically created page and then come back and not have to re-load the data until a full page refresh occurs.
- My dynamically created page included mostly a list so listview() makes the jquery mobile framework refresh the list selected to add the proper css, page() does the same to other page elements; however you may only need to use one or the other depending on your content (or none at all if its just plain text).
- I realize this isn't creating a whole page dynamically because the "wrapper" page is already hard-coded but if you want to add a whole new page you can probably use something like: (untested)

  ```
  $(document).append('<div data-role="page" id="my_page_id"><div data-role="content">FOO BAR</div></div>');
  $('#my_page_id').page();
  ```

If you really want to make it all dynamically created you can check for window.location.hash and create your data-role=page div with the id set as the window.location.hash.

Also I am using Jquery 1.6 and Jquery Mobile 1.0a4.1

I hope something in there can help someone out there :)

Comment: This solution still requires that all the page wrappers exist, before clicking the link. But I have potentially thousands of links, which go to thousands of different pages. Isn't there a way not to create thousands of unused pages?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at jquery's ajax load method? Seems like you could just have it load the page you want and replace the body each time you have a request come back.

[reference](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 0):

In this example on JSFiddle, I take an API call from Flickr and run the results through the jquery tmpl engine to append the new page to the to the document and then call $.mobile.changePage() to the newly inserted page.  I think you'll see how useful the pairing of jquery tmpl + apis + jquery mobile is.

http://jsfiddle.net/sgliser/8Yq36/5/