# Dynamically added page in JQuery is not updating my page with the new style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cordova, jquery-mobile

I've created a function which dynamically generates  and adds it into the body of the HTML. However, it doesn't seem to update the  with my desired styles. I understand that dynamically added content might not inherit the styles, and hence in my listview I called listview("refresh). This time I'm adding a div. I tried adding .page() and the other solutions but they are all not working for me. Am looking for a solution.

```js
function pageGenerator() {
  var strings = "<div data-role='page' id = 'page" + currentId + "' align = 'center' style='background-color: #3e99ff;'><div data-role='main' id = 'content" + currentId + "' class='ui-content'><h1 style='color:#ffffff; text-align:center; font-size: 34px; font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif !important;'>" + ArrayIndex[currentId] + "</h1></div><div data-role='footer' data-id='foo1' data-position='fixed'><div data-role='navbar'><ul><li><a href='#welcomescreen'>Home</a></li><li><a href='#about'>About</a></li></ul></div></div></div>";
  $("#page_body").append(strings);
// Move to this page by ID '#page'
  $.mobile.changePage("#page" + currentId);
  console.log(1);
  console.log(2);

}
```

Comment: Append to `body` (Page-container) unless you have `page_body` Assigned as page-container. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24173950/1771795

Comment: I gave my body ID = page_body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.mobile.initializePage();` is missing between:

`$("#page_body").append(strings);` and `$.mobile.changePage("#page" + currentId);`

Please check the following [stackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6312034/2765346). You will find the same problem and the solution for it ;)

Comment: Can you provide a sample jsFiddle of the structure, please :)